# Is there a way to start where application was last closed?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've created a small application where the user generates prime numbers. The user clicks on a button "generate" and the next prime number gets written on a textView on the screen. This can then be saved to a file on local storage (by clicking a save button). I have also added a load button so the user can load in the latest prime number it got to and continue from there.

My question is: is it possible to actually read the prime number (read the file) without having to click the load button. Can I read a file directly on start up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your activity, you can override onStart() and onStop() and have those methods load and save your file rather than having buttons do those actions.  Something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // load last number
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    // save current number
}
```

Comment: onStart() is only called once per activity if you need to monitor when app is brought from background use onResume

Comment: That's actually not true.  If your app is sent to the background and then brought to the foreground, onStart() and onResume() will be called.

Answer (score 0):

Just use onResume its called every-time your app is brought to foreground.You will be able to do this since you want to fetch data from local and display it in textview. onStart() only get called once

```
 @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    toolbar_title = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
    toolbar_title.setText("Hello World");

}
```

[image]